# How can I have two wildcards in this regex expression?

Tags: regex

<strike>trying to get the following regex:</strike> <- bad english from me :(

I'm trying to get the following input text converted as regex...

`xx.*.aaa.bbb*`

where * are wildcards .. as in .. they represent wildcards *to me* .. not regex syntax.

Any suggestions, please?

### Update - example inputs.

- xx.zzzzzzzzz.aaa.bbb = match
- xx.eee.aaa.bbbzzzz = match
- xx.eee.aaa.bbb.zzzz = match
- xx.aaa.bbb = not a match

Comment: Can you give me a few example strings you need to match?

Comment: You should specify if when you write a `*` there can be included the `.` character or not, or in general which characters are allowed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
^xx\.[^\.]+\.aaa\.bbb.*
```

Comment: @David Fells : xxx.eee.aaa.bbb = match (when it shouldn't be). Notice the three x's at the start...

Comment: @David Fells - wicked :) could you explain the parts of the regex that do what? The answer is awesome but I need to learn also, instead of just getting an answer and then having to ask again in the future :)

Comment: @Pure ^ means start of string. \. matches period - it has to be escaped, because the period itself means "any character at all". The brackets with the plus sign after mean at least one character defined inside these brackets. The ^\. means anything except a period. The .* at the end means anything at all - it will match anything after the bbb.

Comment: @DavidFells Here also you're forcing it to have something between `xx.` and `.aaa`

Comment: @Oscar that's what he requested

Answer (score 2):

You misunderstood the concept of `*` in Regular Expressions.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
xx\..*\.aaa\.bbb.*
```

The thing is:

- a `.` is not a real `.`. It means **any character**, so if you want to match a `.` you must escape it: `\.`
- `*` means that the character that preceeds it will be matched 0 or many times, so how to emulate the wildcard you are looking for? Using `.*`. It will match **any character 0 or many times**.

If you want to match **exactly the entire string**, and **not any substring** that matches the pattern, you have to include `^` at the begining and `$` at the end, so your regex will be:

```
^xx\..*\.aaa\.bbb.*$
```

Comment: Ah, do you think `xx.*.aaa.bbb*` is the string he wants to match? I interpreted this as his regex (but I am not sure)

Comment: This isn't a great regex for the problem. Throwing a .* in the middle of the string is going to make it extremely inefficient. Specificity is always preferable. After all, we don't know the context. He may need this to run against enormous text strings.

Comment: @stema the thing is that he was using `xx.*.aaa.bbb*` as an expression similar to the ones used by windows explorer when you want to find a file. I think he meant: `xx.` then `whatever`, then `.aaa.bbb` and then whatever and he wants to convert it into a regex expression :)

Comment: @DavidFells But you are assuming that when he writes `*` he isn't including there a `.`, and he hasn't said that.

Comment: @Oscar THAT is true. I don't think that's the case though. But he'd have to tells us!

Answer (score 0):

`*` are not wildcards, they mean the preceeding character is repeated 0 or 1 or many times.

And the dot can be any character.

**UPDATE:**

You can try this

```
^xx\.[a-z]+\.aaa\.bbb\.?[a-z]*
```

and you can test it for example [here online on rubular](http://www.rubular.com/r/lLTCaZu2n1)

The `[a-z]` are character groups, within you can define what character is allowed (or not allowed using `[^a-z]`). so if you are only looking for lowercase letters then you can use `[a-z]`.

The `+` means it has to there at least once.

The `\.?` near the end means there can be a dot or not

The `^` at the beginning means to match at the start of the string

A nice tutorial (for Perl, but at least the basics are the same nearly everywhere) is the [PerlReTut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Part-1%3a-The-basics)

Comment: I'm fairly certain he's trying to match a string that fits the pattern where his pattern is not a proper regex, but he's using asterisk as a wildcard.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're saying that * is a wildcard in the 'normal sense', and that your string isn't an attempt at regex, I'd say that `xx\..+\.aaa\.bbb.+` is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to as "wildcard -- not regex syntax" is from [globbing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29). It's a pattern matchnig technique that was popularized in the first Unix version in the late 60's. Originally it was a separate program -- called glob -- that produced a result that could be piped to other programs. Now bash, MS-Dos and almost any shell has this feature built-in. In globbing `*` normally means *match any character, any number of times*.

The regex syntax is different. The `.*` idiom in regex is similar to the `*` in globbing, but not exactly the same. Normally, [`.*` doesn't match line-breaks](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). You usually have to set the *single-line mode* (in Ruby called *multi line*) if you want `.*` to match *any character, any number of times* in regex.